# Return all cell values in a row if Month & Year match a dd/mm/yyyy formatted date cell in that row

Tags: excel

This is possibly a tough one so forgive me while I spell out the exact circumstances and what is needed:

We have a workbook which is populated with data from our support calls (most of it is text) which is then analysed for certain criteria which are just Yes/No options (i.e. incorrect information received, late notice, etc). One of the columns is the date the support call was raised, formatted as dd/mm/yyyy. All of this data is on sheet 2.

What I have been asked to do is to have a management-friendly interface on sheet 1:

two boxes on sheet 1 labelled 'Month' and 'Year' - a manager can enter say January in Month and 2014 in Year and if they match the dd/mm/yyyy of any calls which were raised, this will then extract the whole row of values and place on sheet 3.

On sheet 1, a graph will then be populated from the data on sheet 3 to show things like how many support calls had incorrect information.

Any ideas? I've tried going through VLOOKUPS, MATCH and INDEX and can't find anything which makes any sense to me.

**UPDATE**

Thanks for all the input in such a short time frame. Apologies for not providing more information first time around - was on a tight deadline and had limited time to write the original post. Many thanks to both user2140261 and Scott Gall for the hints and explanations concerning pivot tables. I think that has given me enough information to head in the right direction (I ended up having to do the first graph manually, but seem to have some promising results with my first attempts with pivot tables and charts) so thank you once again.

When I have this properly worked out, I'll post some dummy information showing how it works in case anyone with a similar problem finds it useful.

Comment: It's good you've research them on your own. However, you still have to show us some pseudo-code or logic of what you've tried. We help you out, and you help us help you out by bringing the ammo to the battle, not expecting us to win the war for you. ;) Basically, what have ***you*** tried? :)

Comment: Would most likely be easiest, to add a column with just the month and Year value for each row, Then set up a Pivot Table chart with a slicer, where they will have a list of all possible month year combos, and can simply click on the one they would like

Comment: @user2140261's approach is very sound, as this will give way to a pivot chart, which is flexible enough to view the data as the requirements are selected/changed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

May I suggest the use of a pivot table?

First break the Date Field into multiple columns on sheet two (which do not need to be visible btw).

Formula for Month: = Text(,"mmm")
Formula for Year: = Text(,"yyyy")

Then insert a pivot table on Sheet 1 using the whole data range on sheet two as the source.

Set the two new Columns (Month and Year) as Filters and the user can simply pick a month and year to view (multi select should also be available)

You will need to play around with what to put in the rows and columns and values a bit...
Keep in mind the default "Value" calculation excel will do is Count this is rarely the desired measure for the "Values" usually want SUM.. this can be changed by clicking the small down arrow for the value field and editing the field properties.

Note your graph can then be fed from the resulting pivot table.

Hope you find this helpful... if so please vote up.